# Python IO replace/overwrite text-file with hashcode

Tags: python, hash

I need to overwrite each line of a (txt) file in python with (first 10 digits of) it's  hashcode.

I'm having troubles with the writing part ( I can print it but not write it). the old part of the file('x) should be overwritten with the new part(the hash).

`[FAIL]` File passwords.txt should be transformed from `['x']` to `['2d711642b7']`

Expected value: `['2d711642b7']`
Actual value: `['x', '2d711642b7']`

```
def hash_file(filename):

    import hashlib
    import fileinput
    from hashlib import sha256

    with open(filename,'rb+') as f:

        for line in f:
            hash =sha256(line.rstrip()).hexdigest()
            b = bytes(hash[0:10], 'utf-8')
            f.write(b)
```

Comment: You can't overwrite lines of a file this way, when the data that you want to overwrite has not exactly the same size as the data you write to it. If this is not the case, you have to rewrite the whole file. Filesystems by default don't support "inserting" data.

Comment: Please post the format of your password file.

Comment: it's a .txt file

Comment: Wonderful. What I meant is, how are the lines formed. What do they contain. Please try to be as exact as possible. "They contain Ascii" will not suffice.

Comment: It's a mini exercise from my intro course to python. I posted the test script my professor gave me. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) and open the file in `inplace` mode.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from hashlib import sha256
import fileinput

def hash_file(filename):
    for line in fileinput.input(filename, inplace=True):
        line_bytes = line.rstrip().encode('utf-8')
        hash_10 = sha256(line_bytes).hexdigest()[:10]
        print(hash_10, end='\n')
        # for python 2, print hash_10,
```

Example input:

```
x
y
z
```

becomes:

```
2d711642b7
a1fce43638
594e519ae4
```

P.S : As it turns out, inplace is not actually inplace. Under the hood, a copy of the original file is created.